# Reset size of all images in a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched the forums already but I couldn't find anything like this specifically.

I have a page set up with a bunch of images (gallery type thing) and when they user clicks on an image it will change size from the 200x200 thumbnail to the full sized 600x600.

My issue is that one can continue to click these images and the previous one will remain the enlarged. I would like to limit the amount of expanded images to one.
This is the javascript:

```
function toggleSize(image) {
if (image.style.width != "600px") {
image.style.width = "600px";
image.style.height = "600px";
} else {
image.style.width = "200px";
image.style.height = "200px";
}
```

and the html for each image is as follows:

```
<img class="galleryImage" src="../m/54.jpg" onclick="toggleSize(this)" />
```

the galleryImage class looks like this:

```
.galleryImage {
margin: -2px -2px -3px -2px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

So essentially, in theory, I would want every element of the class galleryImage to reset to its original width and height of 200x200.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can search all your images with a given class (and discard the current) using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) and by looping the result resume them to the starting state.

> Returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given
>   class names. When called on the document object, the complete document
>   is searched, including the root node. You may also call
>   getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements
>   which are descendants of the specified root element with the given
>   class names.

After this, you can call your toggle function.

Code:

```
function resetImages(classToFind, image) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToFind);
    if (!elems) return;
    for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        if (elem === image) continue
        elem.style.width = "200px";
        elem.style.height = "200px";
    }
}

function toggleSize(image) {
    resetImages('galleryImage',image);
    if (image.style.width != "600px") {
        image.style.width = "600px";
        image.style.height = "600px";
    } else {
        image.style.width = "200px";
        image.style.height = "200px";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/DfSbT/

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery solution, code not tested. But image resize will work as you expected.

```
function toggleSize(image) {
    // Get the current image size
    var currentImageHeight = $(image).height();

    // If it is 600, that means user clicked on a enlarged thumbnail
    // Just resize it
    if(currentImageHeight == 600){
        $(image).width(200);
        $(image).height(200);
    }
    // User clicked on other thumbnail. Resize previously enlarged thumbs
    else{
        $('.galleryImage').width(200);
        $(image).width(600);
        $(image).height(600);
    }
}
```